# Can I hold two different types of Schengen Visa (Tourist Type-C and Work Type-D) at the same time?

Tags: schengen, tourist-visas, business-travel

I currently have a 3 year tourist visa (type-c 3 years) and want to apply for a work visa (type-d, 6 month). If my work visa type-d gets accepted, does my tourist visa type-c get cancelled?

Comment: Are you talking about short-stay (“type C”) Schengen visas or something else?

Comment: I have a 3 year type-c tourist visa and want to apply for a work visa type-d

Comment: If it means that it is “entirely ok” to have a Type C and Type D visa at the same time without them cancelling each other, yes, that question answers my question (could you confirm?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schengen Type C and Type D visas at the same time](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105024/schengen-type-c-and-type-d-visas-at-the-same-time)

Comment: @EminoGrande the linked question is same. If you have C visa, you can apply for D visa and stay on D visa wont count towards limits (90/180 rule) of C visa. You C visa wont get cancelled as per accepted answer there

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a business or tourist Schengen visa. In principle, there are only two cases:

- If your visa is a single or double-entry visa, it's tied to a specific trip and should in principle have a short validity. Once you have completed your trip you can apply for another visa.
- If your visa is a multiple-entry visa, it does already implicitly cover all purposes. There is nothing you stopping you from using that visa for business travel (but not work!) You can be asked to provide justification for the purpose your current trip when crossing the border.

If you apply for another Schengen visa even though you already hold a valid one, you should not get one because it's not needed (I think the consulate should decline to process the application and possibly refund the fee rather than formally refuse). There would therefore be no reason to invalidate your existing visa.

Comment: I confused business visa with work visa. 

I have a 3 year multiple entry visa and want to apply for a 6 month working visa. Will the working visa cancel my 3 year tourist visa, if it is approved?

Comment: @EminoGrande Please [edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/168744/edit) your original Question with your clarification

Comment: Edited the initial question for clarification